# Unable to load model index page inside yii2 Tab

Tags: php, yii2, tabs

I want to load model's index page inside tab. I have read yii2 tab document but didn't find suitable example for my case.

My Tab code.

```
<?php
echo Tabs::widget([
    'items' => [
        [
            'label' => 'Actual Timeline',
            $searchModel = new ActualTimelineSearch(),
            $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams),
            'content' => $this->render ('index' ,[
                'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            ]),
           
            'active' => true
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Fixed Task',
            $searchModel = new FixedTaskSearch(),
            $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams),
            'content' => $this->render ('index' ,[
                'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            ]),
     
        ],
    ],
]);
?>
```

From this code I am getting **This site can’t be reached** Error.

Comment: Problem with your server configuration not this page. Did you enabled your local server?

Comment: Code was running fine before i add this code.

Comment: You are mixing variable assignment into array definition. You can't do things like `$searchModel = ...` inside of array definition.

Comment: Move `$searchmodel` and `$dataProvider` declaration outside the array.

Comment: i  declare `$searchmodel` and `$dataProvider` below php tag but still getting same error.